# Unable to install Tensorflow cpu version in Ubuntu16.04 using anaconda

Tags: tensorflow, anaconda

I am facing a problem while installing Tensorflow in Ubuntu 16.04. I was trying to install Tensorfilow CPU supportable version using Anaconda. This is the error I got

> 'tensorflow-1.3.0-cp34-cp34m-linux_x86_64.whl is not a supported wheel
>   on this platform.'

Can any one help me to solve this problem.

Comment: What's your python version? What's the *full* output of `pip --version` ran inside your conda environment?

Answer (score 1):

Try following steps:

First (if you haven't already) install [Pip](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pip_(package_manager))

For Python 2.X

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip python-dev python-virtualenv
```

For Python 3.X

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pip python3-dev python-virtualenv
```

Switch to your Conda environment:

```
source activate your_environment_name
```

And install TensorFlow using Pip:

For Python 2.X

```
pip install tensorflow
```

For Python 3.X

```
pip3 install tensorflow
```